# I can't get rgl to save snapshots or gifs

Tags: r, plotly, imagemagick, rgl, webshot

I can't figure out what is missing to run rgl smoothly. My code and output:

```
pacman::p_load("rgl", "scales", "magick","webshot2")
rgl::plot3d(1:20, 1:20, 1:20)
snapshot3d("~/snap.png", fmt = "png")
movie3d(spin3d(axis=c(0,0,1), rpm=), duration=2, movie="3D-SPIN", verbose=TRUE, type="gif",fps = 2)
```

Output:

```
> pacman::p_load("rgl", "scales", "magick","webshot2")
> rgl::plot3d(1:20, 1:20, 1:20)
> snapshot3d("~/snap.png", fmt = "png")
Error : Chromote: timed out waiting for event Page.loadEventFired
Warning: webshot2::webshot() failed; trying rgl.snapshot()Warning: this build of rgl does not support snapshots
> movie3d(spin3d(axis=c(0,0,1), rpm=), duration=2, movie="3D-SPIN", verbose=TRUE, type="gif",fps = 2)
Error : Chromote: timed out waiting for event Page.loadEventFired
Error : Chromote: timed out waiting for event Page.loadEventFired: this build of rgl does not support snapshotsWriting '3D-SPIN001.png'
Error : Chromote: timed out waiting for event Page.loadEventFired: this build of rgl does not support snapshotsWriting '3D-SPIN002.png'
Error : Chromote: timed out waiting for event Page.loadEventFired: this build of rgl does not support snapshotsWriting '3D-SPIN003.png'
Error : Chromote: timed out waiting for event Page.loadEventFired: this build of rgl does not support snapshotsWriting '3D-SPIN004.png'
Warning: webshot2::webshot() failed; trying rgl.snapshot()Warning: this build of rgl does not support snapshots
```

Session Info:

```
R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.2.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.11.0

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

time zone: Asia/Tokyo
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    stats     graphics  grDevices datasets  utils     methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] plot3Drgl_1.0.4       plot3D_1.4            webshot2_0.1.1        magick_2.8.2          installr_0.23.4       scales_1.2.1         
 [7] rgl_1.2.8             plotly_4.10.3         SeuratDisk_0.0.0.9020 remotes_2.4.2         GenomicRanges_1.52.0  GenomeInfoDb_1.36.1  
[13] IRanges_2.34.1        S4Vectors_0.38.1      BiocGenerics_0.46.0   Signac_1.12.0         Seurat_5.0.1          SeuratObject_5.0.1   
[19] sp_2.0-0              lubridate_1.9.3       forcats_1.0.0         stringr_1.5.1         dplyr_1.1.2           purrr_1.0.2          
[25] readr_2.1.4           tidyr_1.3.0           tibble_3.2.1          ggplot2_3.4.2         tidyverse_2.0.0       devtools_2.4.5       
[31] usethis_2.2.2
```

I installed google chrome. The rglWebGL loads the plot in the html widget, but all the saved png or gif files are solid black/empty.
I am not sure exactly what is wrong/missing, and I have tried fiddling with variety of things but nothing changed yet.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Have you tried using a standard CRAN install (i.e. `install.packages("rgl")`) instead of using `pacman`?

Comment: Yes, `install.packages("rgl")` is how I installed it. I use `pacman::p_load()` instead of `library()` to load packages, but even using `library()` doesn't change anything. I ran `rs.restartR()` and loaded packages using `library()` and still get the snapshot errors.

Comment: I don't have an M1/M2 machine to test on, but it looks as though either the CRAN build is missing functionality, or it depends on a system library that is missing on your system.  I guess you could try building from source, but that can be tricky...

Comment: I closed RStudio and reopened it, then I tried loading the libraries again but they were missing. So I reran `install.packages ()` and somehow it works now. Seems silly in hindsight.

Comment: Okay, glad it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

From these messages:

```
Error : Chromote: timed out waiting for event Page.loadEventFired
Warning: webshot2::webshot() failed; trying rgl.snapshot()Warning: this build of rgl does not support snapshots
```

there appear to be two problems.  First, it tries to use the `webshot2::webshot()` function to take an image, and that fails.  Then it falls back to trying to create the image itself by copying from XQuartz on your screen, and that fails too, because `rgl` is running without OpenGL support.

If you could run `rgl` with OpenGL support that could fix the second failure.  You might need to install XQuartz if you don't already have it installed, and then you should be able to see the `plot3d()` result pop up in a separate window, and the PNG files would be copies of what you have on screen.

I don't know why `webshot2::webshot()` is failing.  You might try installing the development version from Github; use

```
remotes::install_github("rstudio/webshot2")
```

to do that.  I can't tell what version of `chromote` you are using; 0.1.2 is the current release, so updating to that might help if you have an older one.

Comment: I tried `remotes::install_github("rstudio/webshot2")` but I still got the message "Error : Chromote: timed out waiting for event Page.loadEventFired
Warning: webshot2::webshot() failed; trying rgl.snapshot()". I tried `install.packages("chromote")` hoping it was maybe a chromote issue. In the end closing and reopening RStudio allowed rgl to make a little popup window and now it saves snapshots. Sorry that I haven't solved the webshot issue, but at least the workaround works.

Comment: If you run `webshot2::webshot("https://github.com/rstudio/shiny")` does it create a file named `webshot.png` in your current directory, containing a copy of that web page?

Comment: I've seen `webshot2::webshot()` being really slow on some complicated `rgl` scenes, but your example looks simple and displays quickly on my machine.  So I can't suggest anything else.  You could speed things up by forcing the fallback method to be used; use `snapshot3d(...,  webshot = FALSE)`.  You can set an environment variable to make that the default, see the help page.  The quality is generally worse that way, but it is a lot faster.